# Jquery wouldn't hide an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Done this a few times before, but something is wrong this time. Trying to create a popup. As you can guess, initially, it's hidden. It does show up on click, but when i try to close it, nothing happens. Also, when i try to change styles to display:none in developer tools, it switches back to display:block. Currently it's in the head section of the page, but i've tried placing it in the very bottom as well.

html of it

```
<div class="tablecell midlineunit popup-hml middle">
    <div class="hml-popup-bg popupbg ">
        <div class="hml-popup-cnt">
            <div class="closepopup">X</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js of it

```
$(".popup-hml").each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){
         $(this).find(".hml-popup-bg").show();
     });
});
$(".closepopup").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

and of course .hml-popup-bg is hidden in css

Comment: why don't you `.find(".hml-popup-bg").hide()` instead of relying on the number of parents?

Comment: `$(".closepopup").each(function(){    $(this).click(function(){` This made me die a little bit inside.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 don't forget the fact that the first one is like that too

Comment: @Daemedeor Anyway the point is that this piece of code is so badly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this .. no need for **.each()**  just use **.click()**  and you can use **.closest()**  instead of **parent().parent();**

```
$(".popup-hml").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".hml-popup-bg").show();
});

$(".closepopup").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.hml-popup-bg').hide();
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".hml-popup-bg")` I believe you can just do `$(".html-pop-bg", this)` to save you some typings. :)

Comment: still doesn't work. once again, for some reason, even in developers tools i can't change the display style

Comment: @ViciA Make sure you run it only when the document is loaded.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 you are right .. but I really not used to use that way before .. I think I have to develop myself a lil bit :)

Comment: I do use it when document is loaded. Once again, it does show popup on click. It just wouldn't hide it. I've tried different approaches like adding and removing class, hide/show, css('display','none/block'). i can bring the popup out, but can't hide it

Comment: @ViciA as Arathi mentioned you have to use e.stopPropagation(); http://jsfiddle.net/gs6cr13x/

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Its because you close it, but dont stop propagation, so it gets opened again, through bubbling.

```
$(".popup-hml").each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){
         $(this).find(".hml-popup-bg").show();
     });
});
$(".closepopup").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qcqacbyd/

Comment: up +1 for e.stopPropagation(); .. you are totally right

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of jQuery's .each() seems misplaced. What you really want to set up, I think, are 2 event listeners - one to open the popup when you click a button, another to close it when clicking the "X".

You might accomplish this with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".popup-hml", function(){
    $(".hml-popup-bg").show();
});
$(document).on("click", ".closepopup", function(){
    $('.hml-popup-bg').hide();
});
```